# Pending transactions stalled even cancelling with high gas fees

Tags: pending-transactions

I have several pending Ethereum pending transactions that have been stalled for long, as show here: https://etherscan.io/txsPending&m=hf

It doesn't matter how many times I tried to cancel them with higher (>= 10%) gas fees using Metamask, it just didn't succeed. Hope somebody help me.

Comment: On Etherscan it says that your transferring 0 eth. Im not sure why you need to cancel it.

Comment: refer to this if you need additional help:https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28534/122956

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While canceling a transaction with a 0 Eth amount may appear absurd, it can be justified by the need to expedite the cancellation process.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons that might be causing your issue.

Generally, to replace an existing pending transaction, the replacement transaction should have the same nonce.
Looking at your Etherscan link, I can see that the nonce of your second transaction is 2 while the nonce of your first transaction is 1.  In this case, the second transaction won't replace the first transaction. Try the replacement transaction with the same nonce.

If the above does not work, then while having the same nonce as the pending transaction for the replacement transaction, try to increase the Gasprice. You can get a good idea of recent Gasprices of Ethereum using the following link: https://etherscan.io/gastracker.
Adjust your gas price accordingly so that it is sufficient to be mined. The Gasprice you currently use may not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. The nonce for these transactions is neither 0 nor the same, as they are intended to cancel the two preceding pending transactions. The reason they appear to have been pending for just a few hours is because the last-seen data on etherscan.io automatically resets after a certain period of time, despite the actual duration of their pending status.
I have already increased the gas fee by 10% for the transaction with nonce 2, and considering the current high gas fee, I believe it is now at an appropriate level.

Comment: If you want to cancel a transaction, you have to send a transaction with the same nonce and a higher gas price. Were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet. I am unable to determine the appropriate gas fee. The transaction with a nonce of 1 is somewhat challenging. Merely increasing the gas fee by 10% using Metamask is not feasible. In fact, that particular transaction was utilized to cancel a Uniswap transaction with a considerably high gas fee.

Comment: Why don't you send a transaction using Web3js. See: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction or https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction. You can define the gas price then. You can also define the nonce of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can target - cancel, all pending transactions (nonce - one by one) using e.g.  Metamask/Settings/Advanced/"Customize transaction nonce", with the higher maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas - front runned (validated first):

0. Choose alternative Ethereum RPC Server Address - this sometimes help: https://chainlist.org/chain/1
1. Use the same (pending transactions') nonce!

THIS SHOULD BE ENOUGH
Destination address could be the source address. ETH amount could be 0.

You can even tray to send Raw Transaction (e.g. using MyCrypto), something like:

{"to":"0x____","from":"0x____","data":"0x","maxFeePerGas":"0x____","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x____","type":2,"value":"0x____","nonce":"0x____","gasLimit":"0x____","chainId":1}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I increased gas fee by 10% and even more than the current gas fee as suggested by MetaMask, but still failed to send. It always returns an error of "Replacement transaction underpriced."

Comment: I used another wallet MyCrypto to perform this cancelation, and it was done successfully. Thank you so much!